# How to generate a proxy class without client suffix for wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf

when i generate proxy class from WCf service my proxy class name(not file name)is xxxxClient.
i don't want the client suffix for proxy class. Tell me how to generate it.

Comment: Even if this is a community for computer programming, and most programming languages don't have the word "please" in their vocabulary, this community is still composed of people who would appreciate some basic forms of politeness.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control that part. The generation is made using svcutil.exe, and it does not expose  options for naming aside from the namespace (which is also available in the GUI in Visual Studio).